# JavaScript typecasting issue while addition

Tags: javascript

When I use `prompt()` method in JavaScript as follows:

```
var n=prompt("Enter an integer"); //passing 2 as value
n=(n+n);
document.writeln("n+n value is:"+n);
```

Then `(n+n)` gets concatenated as `22` instead of addition as `4`

But when I don't use `prompt()` ie.:

```
var n=2;
n=(n+n) 
document.writeln("n+n value is:"+n);
```

then it works fine for addition and answer is `4`

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt("Enter an integer");` returns `string`

convert it after, you can use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
var n = parseInt(prompt("Enter an integer"));
```

**[SEE FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dfqLfptf/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt to convert String to Int

```
var n = parseInt( prompt("Enter an integer") ); //passing 2 as value
n=(n+n);
document.writeln("n+n value is:"+n);
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var n =prompt("Enter an integer")
```

to

```
var n = Number( prompt("Enter an integer") )
```

As if you do `console.log(typeof n)` you will get a `string` which means n is actually a string.

So concatenation of

```
n = '2' + '2';
```

is `'22'`

Hence you need to change it to a number. For this you can use *[Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)* or *[parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)*.

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared with datatype var can hold any type of variable which is assigned to it at a moment of time.

eg.

```
var j = 1; // here j will be an integer datatype and will act as int after this
var j = "1"; //here j will be a string datatype and will act as int after this
```

in your first case

```
var n=prompt("Enter an integer");
```

here a string will be saved in variable 'n'. hence n will act as a string variable. Therefore (n+n) will result in **concatenation** of two strings.

In your second case

```
var n = 2;
```

In here n is holding an integer therefore n acts as int variable.
Thats why (n+n) results into a SUM instead of concatenation.